# How to access Dom elements inserted by XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript

I am loading html files with an XMLHttpRequest and putting everything in the body tag into an unseen 'storage' div, and then into the page to be seen. That works well.

```
function getModule(module,callback) {
    var modulePath = makeModulePath(module);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
            var el = document.getElementById('storage'); 
            getContent(xhr.responseText, el);
            callback(el);
      }
    };
  xhr.open("GET", modulePath, true);
  xhr.responseType = "";
  xhr.send();
}

<span id="introCurrency" class="introCurrency"><p>Copper standard</p></span>
```

But, always a but right? But when I go to select part(.introCurrency) of that inserted text using document.getElementById('introCurrency') get an error saying 'introCurrency'[null] it is not an object. But querySelectorAll does locate it and I can work with it, but it is a little fudgey:

```
var aModule = 
document.querySelectorAll('.introCurrency');
for (var i=aModule.length; i--;){
    aModule[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

I would much rather use document.getElementById. I hope someone can tell me what's going on. Thank you.

Comment: document property doesn't know about DOM changes after XMLHttpRequest. You can use later binding with specifying selector

Comment: You are trying to access an element by `class` using an `id`.. you cannot use `getElementById` without that node having a unique `id` attribute.

Comment: It has both class and id. Originally it didn't have a class, but added it as a work around.

Comment: You could manipulate the element so you can give it your own id. Currently, I don't really see what your problem might be (from what I see, there is no real question, except that you cannot seem to access it by `id` directly)